# Keyboard catch in C

Tags: c

So I'm thinking about how to catch keyboard activities in C. As we all know, we can type something and press Enter to stream in whatever we want to send to the computer. But the first question is, how to input some untypeable characters like up arrow, down arrow (especially these two guys because I'm using Linux but want to use them for something other than their default meanings), shift, ctrl or whatever. Second, how to make the program proceed right after we press any key, so we don't need to enter and enter all the time. (It's like "Press any key to continue" in Windows).

Answer (score 2):

## There are two ways.

### Using `stty` command.

- you can add `system ("/bin/stty raw");` before you using `getchar()`
- for more details, please `man stty`.

### Using `termios.h`   [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/termios)

- you should change your tty's mode like this `newt.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);`
- for more details, please `man termios.h`

Comment: Setting `stty raw` will put the terminal into a mode where each character is sent as it is typed, with no editing.  The problem is, the terminal will stay in `raw` mode until the characteristics are reset.  So, your program needs to capture the current terminal settings, modify them, and then reinstate the original settings before exiting.  This is a problem whether you use `stty` or `<termios.h>`.  Note that you need to worry about signals.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, you are right. I forget to say that the tty should be reset. So, if the command `reset` will reset to the original mode?

Comment: It gets a bit tricky.  The output of `stty -g` is a string that can be used as the argument to another `stty` command to reset the terminal to the state it was in when `stty -g` was executed.  You just have to read the output of `stty -g`, which might mean using `popen("stty -g", "r");` etc.  Alternatively, using the `<termios.h>` calls, save the current settings ([`tcgetattr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcgetattr.html) and [`tcsetattr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcsetattr.html) or related functions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler are we saying this key combo is never easily done under console in linux

Comment: @zinking: It is most easily done using a library such as `curses` which handles most of this for you.  It is certainly possible to roll your own.  With POSIX and the `tc*()` functions (I assume `tc` is for 'terminal control'; it's a reasonable mnemonic, anyway) it is fairly straight-forward, unlike the platform specific alternatives using `<sgtty.h>` (7th Edition UNIX and BSD) vs `<termio.h>` (System III UNIX; note singular name), etc.  POSIX also has the `cf[io][gs]etspeed()` functions to manage terminal speeds.

Comment: `man termios.h` doesn't work, at least on macOS. `man termios` does.

Answer (score 1):

In the DOS days, there was a `kbhit()` function. If you need that functionality you can look at this thread: [kbhit() for linux](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/63166-kbhit-linux.html).

I vaguely recall trying the user Thantos' function and it working rather well.

I do recommend you read up on what the `tcgetattr()` and `tcsetattr()` functions first.

Answer (score 0):

The "universal" method is getchar ().  Getchar()" uses "buffered input": you don't actually get *any* output until the user presses "Enter".  And it isn't really applicable unless you're using a command prompt (or equivalent).

The old DOS way was getch() and getche(), from "conio.h".  That method doesn't exist in modern C/C++ libraries targeting modern operating systems.

SUGGESTION:

If you want to create a text-mode UI (especially on Linux), take a look at ncurses:

- http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/

If you want to program a game (on Windows or Linux), take a look at SDL:

- http://www.libsdl.org/

=== ADDENDUM ===

I still recommend a library ... but here's a function that illustrates "raw keyboard input" (aka "uncooked", or "non-canonical" input) under Linux:

http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/63166-kbhit-linux.html

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

void changemode(int);
int  kbhit(void);

int 
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int ch;
  changemode(1);
  while ( !kbhit() )
  {
    putchar('.');
  }

  ch = getchar();

  printf("\nGot %c\n", ch);

  changemode(0);
  return 0;
}

void 
changemode(int dir)
{
  static struct termios oldt, newt;

  if ( dir == 1 )
  {
    tcgetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
    newt = oldt;
    newt.c_lflag &= ~( ICANON | ECHO );
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);
  }
  else
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
}

int 
kbhit (void)
{
  struct timeval tv;
  fd_set rdfs;

  tv.tv_sec = 0;
  tv.tv_usec = 0;

  FD_ZERO(&rdfs);
  FD_SET (STDIN_FILENO, &rdfs);

  select(STDIN_FILENO+1, &rdfs, NULL, NULL, &tv);
  return FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &rdfs);

}
```

Comment: but for getchar(), we still need to press enter.

Comment: @user1229490 you can change your tty mode for get a char without `entry`.

Comment: @user1229490: if you're on Windows, look at [ReadConsoleInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684961%28VS.85%29.aspx).  Or use a library like SDL (better for games) or curses (better for text-mode user interfaces).

Comment: @madper: yes, you can change the tty mode; making sure it gets changed back at appropriate times is modestly hard.  You're best off using a library, such as `curses`, to handle the process.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux the best bet for keyboard input is the GNU [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) library.

This provides all the functionality out of the box including emacs and vi editing modes if you want them.

```
/* A static variable for holding the line. */
static char *line_read = (char *)NULL;

/* Read a string, and return a pointer to it.  Returns NULL on EOF. */
char *
rl_gets ()
{
    /* If the buffer has already been allocated, return the memory to the free pool. */
    if (line_read)
    {
        free (line_read);
        line_read = (char *)NULL;
    }

    /* Get a line from the user. */
    line_read = readline ("");

    /* If the line has any text in it, save it on the history. */
    if (line_read && *line_read)
        add_history (line_read);

    return (line_read);
}
```

[MIT](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/rlman_2.html) has some great tutorials.

Comment: Doesn't this wait for the newline to be entered before returning?